# How to redirect any url that have hyphens to home url in asp.net mvc 5

Tags: iis, asp.net-mvc-5, web-config

I am creating a new site for one of my client. Their old site was developed using wordpress and hence it has 100s of broken urls like below:

```
http://www.example.com/best-gym-in-town/
http://www.example.com/video-gallery/
http://www.example.com/fun-stuff/
http://www.example.com/are-you-a-diabetes-patient/
http://www.example.com/john-in-media/
http://www.example.com/photo-gallery/
http://www.example.com/nutrition-program-that-suits-your-lifestyl/
http://www.example.com/our-range-of-fitness-tests/
http://www.example.com/corporate-group-workshops/some-article/another-article
```

I am developing the new site in asp.net mvc 5. I want to write an httpRedirect rule in web.config that can redirect any of the above url to home or any specific page.

so far this is how I am thinking of the solution

```
<location path="about-me">
<system.webServer>
        <httpRedirect enabled="true" destination="/home"
         httpResponseStatus="Permanent" />
</system.webServer>
</location>
```

But I have to write 100s of such entries in web.config. I am looking for a better and efficient alternative

Answer (score 0):

In Global.asax, hook into the `Application_BeginRequest` method and redirect to the homepage from there

```
protected void Application_BeginRequest(object sender, EventArgs e)
{     
    try
    {
        if (HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath.Contains("-")){
            HttpContext.Current.Response.RedirectPermanent("/");
        }
    }
    catch (ThreadAbortException){}
}
```

Optionally, you could hook into the Application_Error method inside Global.asax instead and detect 404's from there

```
protected void Application_Error(Object sender, EventArgs e)
{    
    var exception = Server.GetLastError();   

    if (exception != null && exception == 404)
    {    
        try
            {
            Response.Clear();
            Server.ClearError();
            Response.Redirect("/");    
            }
        }
        catch (ThreadAbortException){}
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try to hook the  beginrequest event and test. Thank you for your suggestion. I will still try to look for a configuration based method.

Comment: If you want to get more advanced, you can add in a lookup against a DB/Config which has mappings for old to new urls.

Comment: np and don't forget to accept the answer if it solves the problem.